# Attempting to retrieve text from <td></td> tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape the link in the code. The artist names and the links come out fine, but I'm not sure how to access the nationality in that second tag.

Here's the code:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def findName():
  page = requests.get('https://web.archive.org/web/20121007172955/https://www.nga.gov/collection/anB1.htm')

  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

  last_links = soup.find(class_='AlphaNav')
  last_links.decompose()

  f = csv.writer(open('h-artist_lastname.csv', 'w')) # Create a file to write
  f.writerow(['Last Name, First Name', 'Nationality', 'Link'])

  artist_name_list = soup.find(class_='BodyText') 
  artist_name_list_items = artist_name_list.find_all('a') 
  artist_nationality_list_items = artist_name_list.find_all('td')

  print(artist_nationality_list_items)

  for artist_name in artist_name_list_items:        
    names = artist_name.contents[0]
    #nationalities = artist_nationality_list_items.contents[0]  
    links = 'https://web.archive.org' + artist_name.get('href')

    #print(nationalities)

    f.writerow([names, links])

findName()
```

If I uncomment the line in the for loop, I get a runtime error which I expect. The print statement gives me this value for artist_nationality_list_items:

```
<td><a href="/web/20121007172915/http://www.nga.gov/cgi-bin/tsearch?artistid=32727">Babbitt, Platt D.</a></td>, <td>American, died 1879</td>, ..... <- follows this pattern for every artist
```

Basically, I want the part with 'American, died 1879'.

Comment: `artist_nationality_list_items[1].text`?

Comment: The loop needs to fetch the nationality for EACH artist on the page, not just the first one. Your solution will only fetch the second element every time.

Comment: ok i didn't pay due attention to your code. i just answered how i would have done it giving your  `tr`. you're parsing the table twice, disorderly. you have no way to know that the data you're retrieving is matching: there's already a bug in the page you gave `Baden, Aiko` and `Baden, Ken` have no matching nationality and it's not gonna end well. HedgeHog's approach is the good one: read your data row by row

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) which accepts CSS selectors with [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to select second `<td>` in each `<tr>` instead of `find_all`, so this:

```py
artist_nationality_list_items = artist_name_list.find_all('td')
```

becomes:

```py
artist_nationality_list_items = artist_name_list.select('td:nth-child(2)')
```

Comment: I understand the logic of just selecting the element directly but I get this error on that line of code when I replace it: NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: @Azure21 I checked it and it works for me, maybe try to reinstall BeautifulSoup and update Python. I tested it on Python 3.8.2

Comment: I can confirm that it does work, for some reason it doesn't work on Google colab, maybe they haven't updated the module yet. Is there an alternative way to go about this? I need to have it work in colab unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe try with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type as error above states so check artist_name_list.select('td:nth-of-type(2)').

Comment: Selecting every second `<td>` will work fine, but result is not the expected, it is a combination with loop, it is quite a list of elements and will throw the same error again. You have to adjust the selection as well as the processing in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can still work with `contents`, but don't get bogged down with all the lists - Select your target more specific and get all information with more flow.

#### What happens?

You're treating `artist_nationality_list_items` (a list) like a single element, that wont work.

#### How to fix?

To get the right result from your `artist_nationality_list_items` you have to iterate it too.

(**Works, but bad idea**):

```
for i,artist_name in enumerate(artist_name_list_items):        
    names = artist_name.contents[0]
    nationalities = artist_nationality_list_items[i+1].contents[0]  
    links = 'https://web.archive.org' + artist_name.get('href')
```

#### Alternativ and much leaner approach

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def findName():
    page = requests.get('https://web.archive.org/web/20121007172955/https://www.nga.gov/collection/anB1.htm')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    f = csv.writer(open('h-artist_lastname.csv', 'w')) # Create a file to write
    f.writerow(['Last Name, First Name', 'Nationality', 'Link'])
    
    for row in soup.select('div.BodyText h3+table tr'):

        names = row.contents[0].text
        nationalities = row.contents[1].text
        links = 'https://web.archive.org' + row.a.get('href')

        #print([names,nationalities,links])

        f.writerow([names,nationalities,links])

findName()
```

Answer (score -2):

A little bit of a botched answer with some sloppy workarounds, but this resulted in what I needed:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def findName():
  page = requests.get('https://web.archive.org/web/20121007172955/https://www.nga.gov/collection/anB1.htm')

  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

  last_links = soup.find(class_='AlphaNav')
  last_links.decompose()

  f = csv.writer(open('b-artist_lastname.csv', 'w')) # Create a file to write
  f.writerow(['Last Name, First Name', 'Nationality', 'Link'])

  artist_name_list = soup.find(class_='BodyText') 
  artist_name_list_items = artist_name_list.find_all('a') 

  i = 2

  for artist_name in artist_name_list_items:   
    str_list = list('td:nth-of-type(i)')
    str_list[15] = str(i)

    selection = "".join(str_list)

    names = artist_name.contents[0]
    nationality = artist_name_list.select(selection)  
    links = 'https://web.archive.org' + artist_name.get('href')

    nat_to_str = str(nationality)
    nat_str_final = nat_to_str[5:len(nat_to_str) - 6]

    #print(nat_str_final)

    f.writerow([names, nat_str_final, links])
    i += 2

findName()
```

Thank you to everyone who answered. Using 'td:nth-of-type()' seemed to work but for me to get every artist on the page, I would need to increase the value inside of nth-of-type every time so I used a list of chars and converted them into a string after incrementing I at each traversal.

Comment: `list('td:nth-of-type(i)')` is surely not gonna work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It did work, you're welcome to try. Hedgehog obviously has a better approach, I just wanted something that works.